# how to call a custom method from inside jar file

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, jar

I am generating a calendar using some utility jar. But in one scenario, I need to call my method instead of the method inside the jar. Now problem is I initially call method one which is inside the jar, that method one calls method two that is again inside the jar and so on. I want a different operation only inside one of the methods which is invoked after 9-10 methods.

So do I need to override all these 10 methods to call my custom mwthod or is there any other way around.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to extend that class and override that method if it is public..but before doing it read its javadoc if it is vailanble..

Comment: Yes. not necessarily all. It depends on what super class's method do.